# Scan service and "This platform is not supported by Coverity"

Tags: xcode, macos, static-analysis, coverity

I'm trying to submit a scan under OS X. The [procedure I am following](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Coverity_Scan) works great under 32-bit and 64-bit Linux, and a similar procedure works great under Winows with `nmake`. On OS X `cov-build` is failing with:

```
$ CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O3" cov-build --dir cov-int make -j 2

Coverity Build Capture (64-bit) version 8.5.0.3 on Darwin 12.6.0 x86_64
Internal version numbers: db70178643 p-kent-push-26368.949

Platform info:
Sysname = Darwin
Release = 12.6.0
Machine = x86_64

[ERROR] This platform is not supported by Coverity.
[ERROR] See documentation for the list of supported platforms.
```

A different OS X machine produces the same error:

```
$ CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O3" cov-build --dir cov-int make -j 2

Coverity Build Capture (64-bit) version 8.5.0.3 on Darwin 13.4.0 x86_64
Internal version numbers: db70178643 p-kent-push-26368.949

Platform info:
Sysname = Darwin
Release = 13.4.0
Machine = x86_64

[ERROR] This platform is not supported by Coverity.
[ERROR] See documentation for the list of supported platforms.
```

I'm having trouble locating the documentation:

```
$ cov-build --help
Coverity Build Capture (64-bit) version 8.5.0.3 on Darwin 12.6.0 x86_64
Internal version numbers: db70178643 p-kent-push-26368.949

No help found for 'cov-build'
```

[Coverity Data Sheet](http://www.coverity.com/library/pdf/CoverityStaticAnalysis.pdf) states OS X is supported, and a [press release states OS X 10.8 is supported](https://www.coverity.com/press-releases/coverity-releases-new-version-of-development-testing-platform/).

- AIX
- FreeBSD
- HP-UX
- Linux
- Mac OS X
- NetBSD
- Solaris
- Windows

Why am I receiving ***`[ERROR] This platform is not supported by Coverity`***, and how do I fix it?

Comment: It might be worth trying `export COVERITY_UNSUPPORTED=1`, though I haven’t tried that in quite a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Mac OSX 10.8 isn't supported in the Coverity release you're using. It's somewhat common for Apple to break compatibility with Coverity with OS releases, unfortunately.

You can export COVERITY_UNSUPPORTED=1. This will bypass the platform support check, however there's no guarantee things will work as expected. You do have reasonably good odds of success.

Comment: Thanks again Caleb. We found we needed your work-ardound of `COVERITY_UNSUPPORTED=1`, and we needed to avoid OS X 10.8's Xcode compiler. Once we moved to MacPorts Clang 3.7, things went as expected. OS X rounds out our recipes for platforms. Also see [prescriptive instructions for Coverity Scan Build](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Coverity_Scan) on our wiki.

Comment: My apologies, I made a mental mistake mapping Darwin 12.6 to OSX 12. The issue here is that Coverity no longer supports OSX 10.8 as of our 8.0 release. The rest of the advice remains the same - set the env var and see what happens. The compiler support is a separate question - I'm glad to see you found a solution that worked for you.

Comment: I’m trying to run Coverity 8.5.0.5 on OS X 10.9 and it’s exhibiting the same symptoms, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

This builds on Flash Sheridan and Caleb's suggestions. The problem was less with the platform and more with the compiler. Xcode 5.0 and 5.1 produced the scan build failure:

```
CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O3" cov-build --dir cov-int make -j 2
...

cat cov-int/build-log.txt
...

"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../
lib/clang/5.0/include/stddef.h", line 29: error #109:

expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have

(pointer-to-) function type

#if !defined(_PTRDIFF_T) || __has_feature(modules)


"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../
lib/clang/5.0/include/stddef.h", line 31: error #59:

function call is not allowed in a constant expression

#if !__has_feature(modules)
...
```

The second work-around depends on Flash Sheridan and Caleb's workaround. It adds "use a different compiler". Below, we use MacPorts Clang 3.7 to perform a scan build.

```
$ CXX=/opt/local/bin/clang++-mp-3.7 COVERITY_UNSUPPORTED=1 CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g3 -O2" cov-build --dir cov-int make -j 8
Coverity Build Capture (64-bit) version 8.5.0.3 on Darwin 12.6.0 x86_64
Internal version numbers: db70178643 p-kent-push-26368.949

/opt/local/bin/clang++-mp-3.7 -DNDEBUG -g3 -O2 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c cryptlib.cpp
/opt/local/bin/clang++-mp-3.7 -DNDEBUG -g3 -O2 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c cpu.cpp
...

Emitted 134 C/C++ compilation units (100%) successfully

134 C/C++ compilation units (100%) are ready for analysis
The cov-build utility completed successfully.
```

---

For anyone interested, we are a Free and Open Source Software project, and we take advantage of the [Coverity Scan Service](https://scan.coverity.com/) at no charge. However, the documentation is kind of light.

If you want prescriptive instructions for performing Scan Builds for Unix, Linux, OS X and Windows, then see [Crypto++ wiki | Coverity Scan](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Coverity_Scan).